# pass location data from uitableview to mapview

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4, mkmapview, core-location

I'm developing an app which parse a xml file and then the content is populated in a uitablaview. This xml file contains geospatial data with information about the location, speed, latitude, longitude for some trucks.  What I want to do is choose one row and then open a detailview with a mkmapview which shows the location of the truck.

Does anyone knows how to load the latitude and longitude of the selected row in the map?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one of the methods in `MKMapView`

```
// You specify lat,lng as coordinate and the map centers around it
- (void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate animated:(BOOL)animated

// You specify a region (center lat,lng and span) and the map centers and zooms appropriately
- (void)setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region animated:(BOOL)animated
```

So for example, in your TableViewDelegate class

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = ... // Obtain coordinate from selected index path
    YourMapViewController * controller = ... // initialize YourMapViewController

    // Your YourMapViewController class has to implement coordinate property as CLLocationCoordinate2D
    controller.coordinate = coordinate;

    // This is an example case you are using navigation controller, it can be modal transition as well.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Your YourMapViewController class has to implement `CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate` property. And in viewDidLoad, you have to call the `senterCoordinate...` method on `mapView` , to center the map.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.coordinate animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: using that can I show the location?

my code for showing the map is the next one:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard ;
    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: 37.183843, longitude: -3.689346}; //this is what I want to get automatically when i select a row.
    MKCoordinateSpan span ={latitudeDelta: 50, longitudeDelta: 50};
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
    
  [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
   mapView.frame = self.view.frame;
}

Comment: Uhm I m not able to do it... Do you mind if you take a look to my code?